# Can't find couchbase data files location on mac

Tags: macos, couchbase

According to documentation it should reside on
~/Library/Application Support/Couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/
In a file named data, but it doesn't seem to be there.

what am I missing?

tx,
Michael

Comment: sandboxed in a container maybe...

Comment: so how do I access it?

Comment: How are you trying to access it?

Comment: Make sure you dont miss the .cb :) maybe the terminal will know better?

Comment: FWIW, on my install (OS X 10.10.4, CB 3) the data files are in the location you mentioned: `~/Library/Application Support/Couchbase/var/lib/couchbase`

Comment: same here. where is it? anyone?

Answer (score 1):

years old question, true, but for anyone that does stumble upon this, the files are in the expected folder, but not visible on Finder. use the terminal to navigate to the folder.

enter:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/data
```

to get to the folder with the bucket source files.